# How to pass icon name from array to

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I´m trying to dinamically pass icon´s name to my html.

It´s working fine for ion-icons, but doesn't work for fontAwesome icons.

**tabs.page.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tabs.page.scss']
})

export class TabsPage {

  public pages = [
    { title: 'Catalog', url: 'home', icon: 'home', type: 'ion' },
    { title: 'Account', url: '/about', icon: 'square', type: 'fa' },
    { title: 'Contact', url: '/contact', icon: 'square', type: 'fa' },
    { title: 'Gallery', url: '/gallery', icon: 'square', type: 'fa' },
    { title: 'Setting', url: '/setting', icon: 'settings', type: 'ion',
 children: [
        { title: 'sub-menu1', url: '/sub-menu1', icon: 'person' },
        { title: 'sub-menu2', url: '/sub-menu2', icon: 'person' },
        { title: 'sub-menu3', url: '/sub-menu3', icon: 'pulse' }
      ] }
  ];

  
  constructor() {}

}
```

***tabs.page.html:***

```
  <ion-menu-toggle *ngIf="p.url"> 
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" slot="start" *ngIf="p.type === 'ion'"></ion-icon>
      <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'p.icon']" slot="start" style="font-size:26px;" *ngIf="p.type === 'fa'"></fa-icon>        
      <ion-label>
        {{ p.title }}
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-menu-toggle>
```

**I getting this error:**

```
error TS2322: Type '"p.icon"' is not assignable to type 'IconName'.
```

**I tried to change my code, but I'm getting these errors:**

```
<fa-icon [icon]="p.icon" slot="start" style="font-size:26px;" *ngIf="p.type === 'fa'"></fa-icon>
```

> error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.

```
 <fa-icon [icon]="['fas', p.icon]" slot="start" style="font-size:26px;" *ngIf="p.type === 'fa'"></fa-icon>
```

> error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconName'.

The icon is showed perfectly when declared directly:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', 'cube']" slot="start" style="font-size:26px;" *ngIf="p.type === 'fa'"></fa-icon>
```

Somebody knows how to fix it?

Comment: You have provided p.icon as string in fa-icon and that is creating an issue

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['far', p.icon]"></fa-icon>
```

Note that the quotation marks are gone, so that its interpreted as the property of an object instead of a string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I'm getting the same error: [webpack-dev-server] ERROR src/app/tabs/tabs.page.html:14:36 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'IconName'. 14 <fa-icon [icon]="['far', p.icon]" slot="start" style="font-size:26px;" *ngIf="p.type === 'fa'"></fa-icon> ~~~~~~ src/app/tabs/tabs.page.ts:5:16 5 templateUrl: 'tabs.page.html', ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Error occurs in the template of component TabsPage.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like font-awesome is expecting an array of strings, so you can actually change your icon values when it's fa like this:

```
  public pages = [
{ title: 'Catalog', url: 'home', icon: 'home', type: 'ion' },
{ title: 'Account', url: '/about', icon: ['fas','square'], type: 'fa' },
{ title: 'Contact', url: '/contact', icon: ['fas','square'], type: 'fa' },
{ title: 'Gallery', url: '/gallery', icon: ['fas','square'], type: 'fa' },
{ title: 'Setting', url: '/setting', icon: 'settings', type: 'ion'];
```

and provide it on html like this:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="p.icon"></fa-icon>
```